# Asp.net button with ajax dont work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to make a button in ASP.NET that call a ajax function and return another ASP.NET, with a method do search in my database. When I click into the button the ajax function it doesn't trigger, doesn't do anything.This Ajax will take something that the user will digit, like a ZIP-code, and will search in my database.

```js
var cepjs = $('#MainContent_cepBrasil').val();
        alert(cepjs);
        $('#ButtonCEP').click(function () {
             alert('cliquei');
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CEP.aspx/Consulta_CEP",
                data: JSON.stringify({ scep: cepjs}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#MainContent_cepBrasil') = result.CEEP.localCEP;
                    $('#MainContent_ufEnderecoBrasil') = result.CEEP.localUF;
                    $('#MainContent_codMunicipioEnderecoBrasil') = result.CEEP.localMunicipio;
                    $('#MainContent_tpLogradouro') = result.CEEP.localTpLog;
                    $('#MainContent_descLogradouroBrasil') = result.CEEP.localLogradouro;
                    $('#MainContent_complementoBrasil') = result.CEEP.localComplemento;
                    $('#MainContent_bairroBrasil') = result.CEEP.localBairro;

                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<!--<input     Type="button" ID="ButtonCEP" name="btnConsultar_CEP" Class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Consultar" />-->
<button id="ButtonCEP">Consultar</button>
</div>
```

I've try it to do everything in the ajax, even change the click.function to on('click', function()), but didn't work too, and i try to use some different forms in button style, with button and input type button.

Anyone could help me, I'll appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you wrap this code into `$(function(){  })` so that it runs after DOM is loaded. Otherwise it can happen that you execute this code before the button even exists on the page

Comment: 1) Did you place your handler *after* the button? 2) Did you wrap it into `$(document).ready`? 3) Does id of the button in **generated** HTML (in browser) equal to `ButtonCEP`?

Comment: Yes I've already have done this. and try even to use another button, but it didn't work too

Comment: Try adding `event.preventDefault();` at the top of your `$.click`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors here, you are not including the jquery source file, and not waiting for the doc to be ready

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var cepjs = $('#MainContent_cepBrasil').val();
    alert(cepjs);
    $('#ButtonCEP').click(function () {
             alert('cliquei');
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CEP.aspx/Consulta_CEP",
                data: JSON.stringify({ scep: cepjs}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#MainContent_cepBrasil') = result.CEEP.localCEP;
                    $('#MainContent_ufEnderecoBrasil') = result.CEEP.localUF;
                    $('#MainContent_codMunicipioEnderecoBrasil') = result.CEEP.localMunicipio;
                    $('#MainContent_tpLogradouro') = result.CEEP.localTpLog;
                    $('#MainContent_descLogradouroBrasil') = result.CEEP.localLogradouro;
                    $('#MainContent_complementoBrasil') = result.CEEP.localComplemento;
                    $('#MainContent_bairroBrasil') = result.CEEP.localBairro;

                }
            });
        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<!--<input     Type="button" ID="ButtonCEP" name="btnConsultar_CEP" Class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Consultar" />-->
<button id="ButtonCEP">Consultar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: In my code I've already have the src code to ajax.google, It's not showing because it's a large code, and I've already use the $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

Can you try invoking the function after DOM is ready by

$(document).ready(function() {

//

});

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I've got the solution, I was calling the .ready function into another .ready function, and that was the problem, i just don't know why , but I put this function out off it in the beginning of the code, and it work. Thanks for the helping.